# C# COM port receive info

Tags: c#, .net, ports

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public class SerialPortListener
{

    #region Properties

    public SerialPort _Port { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs> DataReceived;

    #endregion


    public void Start()
    {
        Close();

        //todo: get attached COM names...
        List<string> names = SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList();

        // todo: for testing, let's pick first...
        string name = names.FirstOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return; // todo: throw error that no devices are attached...

        _Port = new SerialPort(name);
        _Port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        _Port.Open();
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        string data = port.ReadExisting();
        if (DataReceived != null)
            DataReceived(this, new SerialDataEventArgs(data));
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (_Port != null && _Port.IsOpen)
            _Port.Close();
    }

}

public class SerialDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SerialDataEventArgs(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Byte array containing data from serial port
    /// </summary>
    public string Data;
}
```

where com port name is "COM1", and I have connected a handheld barcode scanner.
I noticed that it works only when I put a breakpoint on _Port.Open() and then step over it after which I press continue in the debugger. Then scanning works and DataReceivedHandler is called.

Otherwise it doesn't work and scanner also doesn't get a good read beep.
I Tested scanner in the application I got from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application) ,where it works fine every time.

My question is why doesn't it work every time like in example app and what can be done differently to make it work.

Comment: what is the baudrate of the scanner, and why don't you specify it?

Comment: Do you gracefully close the port an application exit? If so do you quit the app while debugging or do you hit "stop"? My first thought would be the port is not correctly freed. And you should use some try/catches to figure out what's the matter when things go south. Another thing: You take the first portname in the list. Where do you make sure it is actually "COM1" ?

Comment: @MongZhu the baudrate is left as default 9600

Comment: @Fildor I will try to use the "Close" and then let you know, thanks :)

Comment: Make sure scanner is connected before executing the `start` function and if you want to recognize when any device is getting connected and auto start then that's the different question. I can provide code if you want to recognize when any devices are connected to the serial port if you need it.

Comment: @Fildor adding Close actually worked, can you create a answer so I could upvote?

Answer (score 1):

When using COM ports, it is important to close them after use.
Otherwise they will remain unavailable for opening again until they are closed.

Therefore, when debugging, it is important to not simply hit "stop debugging" but have some cleanup code running in all circumstances that will gracefully close the port.

I'd also recommend adding an unhandled exception handler in the App that makes sure the port will be closed before exiting the Application in case of an unexpected error.

Also, the documentation of the "[Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open(v=vs.110).aspx)" method states under "Remarks":

> The best practice for any application is to wait for some amount of time after calling the Close method before attempting to call the Open method, as the port may not be closed instantly.